# ROS enviroenment variable setup

Tags: rosmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi ,
I am new in ROS and I want to use ROS to make dvo (dense visual odometry) package
the command is :
rosmake dvo_core dvo_ros dvo_benchmarke

but it can't execute and the error is :

sara@sara:~$ rosmake dvo_core dvo_ros dvo_benchmark
[ rosmake ] rosmake starting...                                                 
[ rosmake ] Packages requested are: ['dvo_core', 'dvo_ros', 'dvo_benchmark']    
[ rosmake ] Logging to directory /home/sara/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20140225-192413
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/hydro/bin/rosmake", line 55, in <module>
    if rma.main():
  File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosmake/engine.py", line 741, in main
    makedirs_with_parent_perms(self.log_dir)
  File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosmake/engine.py", line 91, in makedirs_with_parent_perms
    os.chown(p, s.st_uid, s.st_gid)
OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/home/sara/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20140225-192413'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/hydro/bin/rosmake", line 55, in <module>
    if rma.main():
  File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosmake/engine.py", line 741, in main
    makedirs_with_parent_perms(self.log_dir)
  File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosmake/engine.py", line 91, in makedirs_with_parent_perms
    os.chown(p, s.st_uid, s.st_gid)
OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/home/sara/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20140225-192413'
sara@sara:~$

What should I do ?

Thanks a lot in advance

Sarah

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/133106/ros-enviroenment-variable-setup/) by [sara.ershadi](https://answers.ros.org/users/12406/sara.ershadi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-02-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems to me that you somehow made the .ros directory in your home accessible only be root.
The easiest way to fix that is probably to (backup anything important and then) delete it completely.

You might need to run `rosdep update` (NOT `sudo rosdep update`!) again.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2014-02-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1